# escape double curly brackets in string.format

Tags: escaping, jquery-templates, string.format

I want to escape {{if IsEnabled==true}}checked{{/if}} and drop it into a checkbox from a HtmlHelper. It doesnt seem to escape the double bracket, single it has no problem with.

Help!